# Run commands from a file in separate detached sessions

Tags: bash, shell, daemon, tmux, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run 150+ commands that require a prompt of a yes or no depending on the output of these commands which needs to be manually verified.

I'd like to run all these commands at the same time because it takes about 30 to 60 seconds to run. I've tried to do this in `screen` but I'm finding it difficult for it to wait for the command's prompt without killing itself.

I have zero preference on what cli command to use, whichever works. I'm open to `tmux`, `screen`, `termocil`, `itermocil`, `tmuxinator`, etc.

Attempts

```
screen -dmS test "bash -c 'ls'"
screen -dmS test "ls"
```

Then when I try to access it via `screen -r` I see this output

```
=== Window terminated (Thu Dec 13 23:33:13 2018) ===
```

Comment: Can you give us more information on why `screen` killed itself before the command finished? How did you start `screen` and the command inside it? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: @Socowi I could not get it to work using `screen` but I found [this for `tmux`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41301473/2965993) and it helped me out with a little bit of tweaking.