# "npm start" on multiple directories

Tags: python, node.js, terminal

I have a project that requires running multiple services each on a different folder and a db server.

How can I automate running all of them each in it's own terminal?
entering each folder and running "npm start" on separate terminal window.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run like this

```
npm start & mongod & node public/app.js &
```

& makes the process run in the background so once the session is closed the server stops
But you can use nohup to keep it running

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

> concurrently "command1 arg" "command2 arg"

Answer (score 0):

**In development:**

Take a look at `tmux` or `screen`. They provide an easy way to run multiple shells. You can even automate the startup ([How to write a shell script that starts tmux session, and then runs a ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902929/how-to-write-a-shell-script-that-starts-tmux-session-and-then-runs-a-ruby-scrip)), and there are tools to configure it easily, eg. https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil

**In production:**

You probably don't wan't production apps/services running in a detached terminal. There are more suitable tools for that with proper logging et cetera. I have a good experience with:

- [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), for running Node apps
- [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), for running… anything, really