# How to run python file inside tmux session?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, cron, tmux

I am trying to run python script inside `tmux` session. I wrote a command (`tmux new-session -d -s my_session`) which is running fine from `crontab`.

But when I am trying to run python or shell file with `tmux new-session -d -s my_session 'python3 test.py` or `tmux new-session -d -s my_session 'sh test.sh`
The script doesn't run. I used the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902929/how-to-write-a-shell-script-that-starts-tmux-session-and-then-runs-a-ruby-scrip).
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**
You can separate tmux commands with `\;`, then use the `send-keys` command to send the command to the active window.
In your case you can use:

```
tmux new-session -d -s my_session \; send-keys "python3 test.py" Enter
tmux new-session -d -s my_session \; send-keys "sh test.sh" Enter
tmux new-session -d -s my_session \; send-keys "python3 -m http.server 8080" Enter
```

You can find more about `send-keys` options on the [tmux manpages section for send-keys](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#send-keys):

> **send-keys** [**-lMRX**] [**-N** repeat-count] [**-t** target-pane] key ...
>   (alias: **send**)
>   Send a key or keys to a window. Each argument key is the name of the key (such as ‘`C-a`’ or ‘`NPage`’) to send; if the string is not recognised as a key, it is sent as a series of characters. The **-l** flag disables key name lookup and sends the keys literally. All arguments are sent sequentially from first to last. The **-R** flag causes the terminal state to be reset.
>
> **-M** passes through a mouse event (only valid if bound to a mouse key binding, see [MOUSE SUPPORT](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#MOUSE_SUPPORT)).
>   **-X** is used to send a command into copy mode - see the [WINDOWS AND PANES](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#WINDOWS_AND_PANES) section.
>   **-N** specifies a repeat count.

The `send-keys` syntax is described on the [Key Bindings section](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#KEY_BINDINGS) of the [tmux manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1). The key names used by `send-keys` are the same ones used by `bind-key`.

I usually work with different configuration files, on top of a base file.

Imagine that you've your tmux configuration in `~/.tmux.conf` I then create different configuration files in my `~/.tmux/` folder. As an example I can have a python configuration file (use the `attach` if you want to enter in the session):

```
# To use this configuration launch tmux with the command:
#   > tmux -f ~/.tmux/python.conf attach
#

# Load default tmux config
source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# Create session and launch python script
new-session -s python -n python -d -c ~/src/python/
send-keys "python test.py" Enter
```

This gives me the flexibility to create much more complex sessions.

Comment: I tried this tmux new-session -d -s myTempSession `sh runPython.sh` but this didn't work. And how about ~/.tmux.conf` how do I create it. Please guide.

Comment: That's is your custom tmux configuration, if you're not using one, you can simply comment that line.

Comment: Cool, But this back ticks "`" isn't working. Can you please check?

Comment: Sorry, you're right the back ticks was definitely not working! I've corrected the answer using \; and the send-keys to execute the command in the newly created tmux session. Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Is there any reference where I can study about `send-keys` and other things about tmux and it's syntax?

Comment: I've added few notes about send-keys syntax.